# How to get SPField and avoid exception that it is not exists?

Tags: column

I run now this code and got an exception on the first row. How to avoid an exception when the column doesnt exists?

```
SPField field = contentType.Fields.GetFieldByInternalName("ArticleStartDate2");
if(field != null)
{
   // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a method on the [`SPFieldCollection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfieldcollection.aspx) class called [`ContainsField`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfieldcollection.containsfield.aspx).

You can use that method to check if the field is available before trying to access it.

EDIT:
Also notice that there is another method called [`ContainsFieldWithStaticName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.spfieldcollection.containsfieldwithstaticname.aspx) you can use if you only have the field static name.